# How do I get .service files for gnome-keyring?

Tags: linux, dbus, gnome-keyring

My ultimate goal is to get gnome-keyring functioning as a credential storage for use by shell and python scripts on an RHEL 6 server. The admins installed package gnome-keyring-2.28.2-8.el6_3.x86_64, and the gnome-keyring-daemon does start.

When I try to access it from Python though, I get an error `The name org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files`

Googling for that error returns a number of issues that are solved by "install gnome-keyring", but that's been done on this system already.

I'm not sure if I'm looking at a config issue, or an ancient-version issue, or something else.

Edit:
@grawity's answer adds quite a bit of clarity in general. I suspect you're right about gnome keyring, as what I'm doing is this:

launch gnome-keyring-daemon into a dbus session: `dbus-run-session -- gnome-keyring-daemon --start`

export GNOME_KEYRING_SOCKET, SSH_AUTH_SOCK, GNOME_KEYRING_PID

launch a shell into a dbus session: `dbus-run-session -- bash`

export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

call python-keyring and have it list the backends it finds: `pipenv run python -m keyring --list-backends`

Answer (score 0):

D-Bus `.service` files are necessary for automatic "on demand" activation of services. Some of them, however, aren't *meant* to be activated on-demand – instead they're meant to be launched explicitly by the desktop environment or by a PAM module or such. Once started this way, gnome-keyring-daemon will claim the bus name without needing a .service file.

The real issue is likely with the way programs *connect* to GNOME Keyring. It is not a system service; it is a per-user service, but it is accessible through the D-Bus "session bus", which as the name implies is usually per-session. (Although this has changed recently with many Linux distributions moving to the "user bus" model, but from the PoV of RHEL 6 that's still distant future.)

When gnome-keyring-daemon starts, it connects to what it sees as the "current" session bus (i.e. what's set in $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_SOCKET) and will claim a name on that bus. But if your other SSH sessions do not have this environment variable, they won't be able to find the correct bus (in the worst case they'll start a *new* session-bus instance every time).

So depending on the method you use to start gnome-keyring-daemon, you might want to manually start the `dbus-daemon --session` instance as well (using `dbus-run-session` or `dbus-launch`), and you need to make sure all SSH sessions belonging to that user know the same $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_SOCKET. For example, after launching the daemon you could store the environment variables in ~/.dbus.env which other SSH sessions automatically "source" from their ~/.profile and such.

For reference, if the daemon is started by pam_gnome_keyring (as it is with GNOME) and you are *not* using pam_systemd on this machine (which probably doesn't exist on RHEL 6), the initialization process has two stages and works like this:

1. PAM goes through the 'open_session' stage and runs `gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login`.
2. The daemon opens a "control" Unix socket somewhere.
3. The desktop environment starts a session bus via `dbus-launch` and exports $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_SOCKET to be available to all programs.
4. The desktop environment calls `gnome-keyring-daemon --start`, which uses the control socket to inform the keyring daemon of the $DBUS… variable's contents.
5. The keyring daemon connects to the session bus and claims the `org.freedesktop.secrets` bus name.

Comment: Thanks for this; I added information about the steps I was taking to my post if that sheds any light on what I'm doing wrong to get gnome keyring on the bus

Comment: Your edit shows that you're starting two completely separate dbus sessions?

Comment: I guess I am (oops) -- but fixing that (I think) by doing `dbus-run-session -- bash` `gnome-keyring-daemon --start` `pipenv run etc` to keep it all in one session doesn't change the error I was getting.

Comment: I also just realized that `/etc/pam.d/login` doesn't have `auth optional pam_gnome_keyring.so` or `session optional pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start` so might getting those added be a place to start?

Comment: How do you plan on unlocking the encrypted keyring? Will you want to use the system login password, or a separate password?

Comment: System login would be preferable